Py4JJavaError when trying to create SparkSession in Jupyter notebook
I observed above error when I am trying to create SparkSession. I am stuck on this for some time.
When i am executing this in Jupyter Notebook:
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('appname').getOrCreate()
Getting this error:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getSubject is supported only if a security manager is allowed
at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.getSubject(Subject.java:347)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:648)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1(Utils.scala:2561)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2561)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:501)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:485)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1575)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I also got the same error today. I was using jdk-23.  I switched to jdk-17 and it got resolved. spark release documentation says spark runs on jdk-17.
Hope this helps.
